# Appending array with useState hook not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks, react-state-management, use-state

I am using the below code and expect that I will recieve an array of multiple objects as I am using "...".

```
const [csv, setCsv] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    d3.csv(fileName, function(fileContents) { setCsv(
        [...csv,{
            'key': fileContents['Licenseno'],
            'First Name': fileContents['First Name'],
            'Address': fileContents['Street #'] + " " + fileContents['Stname'] + " " + fileContents['Suffix'] + " " + '0' + fileContents['Zip']
        }]);
    });
},[])
```

Instead, console.log reveals that csv[] is being re-written for every fileName row and only ever includes one object at a time.

To see whether this was related to d3 (which I have never used before), I declared a const arrayVar = [] and .appended- this worked the way I wanted. So it seems to be the useState hook... any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of using `setState` is by passing a function.

```
// instead of
setCsv([...csv, { key: '...' });

// use this:
setCsv((currentState) => [ ...currentState, { key: '...' } ]);
```

When you pass a function to setState, the current state will be passed as argument to that function. This way you don't have to add the state to your `useEffect` dependency array.

You can find more information in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).